# How can we change heading with respect to time using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the heading of the web page. Like I have

```
<h1>hey there!</h1>
```

so want to change this heading text with another text with respective time.
and changes should be in the loop.

like I used my values to be store in an array.
eg. var values = [ 'hi', 'hello', 'bye']
how can I use the set.timeout function in for loop to change those values continuously.

Comment: Please add code for what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

```js
let targetElement = document.querySelector('h1');
var values = ['hi', 'hello', 'bye'];
var totalArraylength = values.length;
var counter = 0;
setInterval(() => { 
    if(counter<totalArraylength){
        targetElement.innerHTML = values[counter];
        counter += 1;
    }else{
        counter = 0
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h1>hey there!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simple manner with DOM you can do it like this way

```js
var count = 0;
var titleList = ['hi', 'hello', 'bye'];
var intervalsFunc = setInterval(() => {

 if ( count >= (titleList.length - 1)) {
      clearInterval(intervalsFunc);
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = titleList[count] ;
    count++
   
  },
  1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>JavaScript can Change HTML</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Title can be changed by using the `title` tag. If you wanna count how many times for the loop, you can implement it by taking a look on the above answers.

```
const title = document.querySelector('title')
const values = [ 'hi', 'hello', 'bye']


values.forEach((elem) => {
   setInterval(() => {
       title.innerText = elem
   }, 2000)    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let values = ['My', 'array', 'values'];
let currentIndex = 0;
let changeValue = () => {
  let node = document.querySelector('h1');
  node.innerText = values[currentIndex];
  if (currentIndex < values.length + 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      currentIndex++;
      changeValue();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
changeValue()
```

```html
<h1>hey there!</h1>
```

Comment: Resulting in ``undefined``, please check your solution again.